# how to use mysql extract year in where clause

Tags: mysql

i want to search on date field with year. i used Extract like this but it generates error.

```
  SELECT *  FROM (blog) WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM blog_dt) = '2014'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (blog) WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM blog_dt)= '2014' ;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM (blog) WHERE YEAR(blog_dt)='2014';
```

Comment: First syntax works smoothly with PHP Version 7.3.5 and Laravel 5.8; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's much simpler:

```
SELECT *  FROM (blog) WHERE YEAR(blog_dt) = 2014
```

See the manual:

> [YEAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)
>
> Returns the year for date, in the range 1000 to 9999, or 0 for the
>   “zero” date.
>
> mysql> SELECT YEAR('1987-01-01');
>
> ```
>      -> 1987
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra apostrophe after the EXTRACT() function, remove it and it should work (although @VMai's solution is much easier and more readable

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Function DateFormat available in MYSQL.

```
select * FROM blog WHERE DATE_FORMAT(blog_dt,'%Y')='2014';
```

For more Date Related Functions visit [URL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)